# Encoded string is not working in swift

Tags: swift, uiimage, uiimagepngrepresentation

In my swift App, I need to convert Image as String, then I need to send to Server , i.e POST. Then, if I need to GET, I dont want to decode that. Response having Image file name and path.

**ONline Converter:**

If I convert the sample image through online converter, [HERE.](http://www.dailycoding.com/Utils/Converter/ImageToBase64.aspx) I am getting following string. If I pass this string to API, I can get image successfully.

**Output:**

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJAAAACQCAYAAADnRuK4AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR.... .....CIBhIIgQRCIIEQSCAQAgmEQAIhkEAIJBAIgQRCIIEQSCAEEgiEQAIhkEAIJCgN/F+AAQAXoGXl+IGgwwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

**Through My Coding**

If I convert the sample image through Coding, I am getting following string. If I pass this string to API, Successfully adding. But, I unable to view that image manually in browser too.

More Over,, Two **Output Strings** are not same. I dont know why? Kindly guide me, how to solve this?

**Code:**

```
var image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "home_recharge.png")!
        var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.allZeros)
        println("base64String    \(base64String)")
```

**Output:**

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJAAAACQCAYAAADnRuK4AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAABxpRE9UAAAAAgAAAAAAAABIAAAAKAAAAEgAAABIAAAKygzM7MwAAAqWSURBVHgB7FwJ0JZDHC9yhJTkLuRMjuQ+opAr5zjGqAwZx...... .......FlIs5ASSDNQLA7EMtYMpBlICaQZKBYHYhlrBtIMpATSDBSLA7GMNQNpBlICaQaKxYFYxpqBNAMpgTQDxeJALGPNQJqBlECagWJxIJaxZiDNQP8B+6MkTad9NtcAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

Comment: Output strings are different because online converter and `UIImagePNGRepresentation()` may use different algorithms or compression options.

Comment: What do you mean by "I unable to view that image in browser"? How do you try to do this? When you post your image to API your server must decode it from base64 and write it to file. So you can open this file and view the image.

Comment: yes u r right @mixel . But,, From response I am getting Image path as "http://192.178.2. ...... /image.jpg"

Comment: And what's the matter? I don't understand.

Comment: Bcos,, If I pass that,, iOS code string,,,, to API,,,,
Response is coming,,, but Image not opening,,,,, If I opened in Browsers,,,,, Image contain errors… like that alerts are shown…
But,, If I pass online converter’s String,, to API,,,,, that same image can be opened in browsers too...
This is my probs.  @mixel

Comment: You encode image as png with `UIImagePNGRepresentation` but server saves it with `.jpg` extension and browser tries to open image as JPEG. Replace `UIImagePNGRepresentation` with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or on server save image with `.png` extension.

Comment: No @mixel . Same PNG file is opening as JPEG on browser, when pass online converter's encoded string in API.

Comment: Just try it. Your current code is not correct because it opens png image as jpeg. Anyway you should fix it. The reason browser can open online converter result image despite it has wrong extension is possibly that `UIImagePNGRepresentation` strips the image of its meta data and online converter not so browser can not figure  the real type of image with wrong extension without meta data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use png image representation but server saves the image with `.jpg` extension so browser tries to read image as JPEG file and fails.

You should replace `UIImagePNGRepresentation` with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or save image with `.png` extension.

The reason why browser can open online converter result image despite it has wrong extension is possibly that UIImagePNGRepresentation strips the image of its meta data and online converter not so browser can not figure the real type of image with wrong extension without meta data.